# Constraint Reference 'ApiVersion' counld not resolved to a type

Tags: api-versioning

[Constraint Reference Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrl70.png)

Hi,
I'm using .Net 6 Web API with versioning, my versioning works just fine in Swagger, but when I reference my API from MVC Framework (.NET 6), I'm getting an exception that says :

InvalidOperationException: The constraint reference 'apiVersion' could not be resolved to a type. Register the constraint type with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteOptions.ConstraintMap'.

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddApiVersioningConfig(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApiVersioning(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            cfg.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;             // In case if the user doesn't specify the version, so we assume to use the default one (v1)
            cfg.ReportApiVersions = true;                               // This will mention which API the user is currently using (Header).
           

            // 1-  api/v1/clients/ => In order to read the segment that contains the version eg.

            // 2- api-version : 1.0 => In case the user provides the version as header  

            // 3- ?api-version=1.0 => From query approach

            cfg.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(
                new HeaderApiVersionReader("X-version"),
                new QueryStringApiVersionReader("api-version"),
                new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader(),
                new MediaTypeApiVersionReader("ver"));
        });

        return services;
    }
}
```

---

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(opt =>
{
    var provider = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();

    foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
    {
        opt.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json",  description.ApiVersion.ToString());
    }
});
```

Many thanks for your help :)

KingKali

Comment: When you say it's _"working fine"_ in Swagger, do you mean the routes are being documented, the endpoints are invokable, or both? With a bit more information, I can give you a complete answer. The `ApiVersionRouteConstraint` is registered through `IPostConfigureOptions<RouteOptions>` with the name configured in `ApiVersioningOptions.RouteConstraintName` which defaults to `apiVersion`. You've called `AddApiVersioning` so unless there is so other part of the routing system you've changed, it's hard to imagine it's not working.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've managed to fix it

Comment: What did you do to fix it?

Answer (score 9):

I was receiving the same error on my Web API that is deployed on Azure App Service but didn't receive the error locally.

Error:
`InvalidOperationException: The constraint reference 'apiVersion' could not be resolved to a type. Register the constraint type with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteOptions.ConstraintMap'.`

### Solution:

In `Startup.cs` file I've added the following line:

```cs
services.AddApiVersioning();
```

That method is located in `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`.

After redeploying on our Azure App Service with that change, everything was working as expected.

Comment: Sorry but it's hard to understand what the difference is between the `AddApiVersioning(options => ...)` declaration inserted in the question and the `AddApiVersioning()` declaration you inserted in the "solution", since both implementations of `AddApiVersioning` are within the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace and obviously the person who wrote the question will also have recalled his startup method.
So removing the `ApiVersionOptions` from the method instance did it work or what?

Answer (score 1):

**Add below code in program.cs**

```
.AddApiVersioning()
.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
 {
    options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VV";
    options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you are using the wrong nuget package.
You have Asp.Versioning.WebApi and you have Asp.Versioning.Mvc

If you use the original MVC controllers for your Api, you need to use Asp.Versioning.Mvc, not Asp.Versioning.WebApi.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Asp.Versioning.Mvc/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Asp.Versioning.WebApi/